# Rainfall guage stations outside the watershed

Tags: hydrology, rainfall, storms, watershed, runoff

How can I determine the rainfall depth for an event over the watershed, if I just have two stations, S1 and S2, that are outside the catchment?

Methods I have thought of were to take the average of S1 & S2 or just to use the Theissen polygon method. If anyone has another idea or previous experience with this situation your help would be appreciated.

[image: How i can determine the rainfall depth for an event over the watershed ? If just i have S1 and S2 stations (two stations) outside the catchment.]

Comment: I thought to take average of S1 & S2 or just to use Theissen polygon method ? Please if you have another idea or previous experience with this situation help us with your answer.  Regards

Comment: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/17020/can-i-interpolate-rainfall-data-from-stations-outside-of-watershed-for-the-water/17039#17039

Comment: Your map needs a scale. I don't know how you will make polygons with only 2 stations.

Comment: I meant if there is a way for this situation ? Regardless the scale and calculations procedure